# WebGL - change colours for between objects

Tags: javascript, colors, webgl

I am new to WebGL and want to know how to change between colours for different objects.

I have a data for a circle and a field in one array. I want to display the field in green, and display the circle on the field in blue.

I am getting the error for my vColor attribute (which doesn't not display my circle, only the field):
`[.Offscreen-For-WebGL-05A18588]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawArrays: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 1`,

However, when I remove the code to set up the vColor attribute, I can see the circle but both field and circle are displayed in black. Any clue where I am going wrong?

Shader code:

```
    <script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
        attribute vec4 vPosition;
        attribute vec4 vColor;
        varying vec4 fColor;

        void main() {
            fColor = vColor;
            gl_Position = vPosition;
        }
    </script>

    <script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
        precision mediump float;
        varying vec4 fColor;

        void main() {
            gl_FragColor = fColor;
        }
    </script>
```

JS code:

```
//cirlce data
var pi = 3.14159;
var x = 2*pi/100;
var y = 2*pi/100;
var r = 0.5;
var center = vec2(0.0, 0.0);
//data for gpu
var vertices = [
    vec2(-7.0,-1),
    vec2(-0.6, 0),
    vec2(0.6, 0),
    vec2(6.0, -1)
];

var vertexColors = [
    vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ),  // black
    vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ),  // red
    vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // yellow
    vec4( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ),  // green
    vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 ),  // blue
    vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 ),  // magenta
    vec4( 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0 )   // cyan
];

window.onload = function init()
{
    canvas = document.getElementById( "gl-canvas" );

gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL( canvas );
if ( !gl ) { alert( "WebGL isn't available" ); }

vertices.push(center);
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    vertices.push(add(center, vec2(r*Math.cos(x*i), r*Math.sin(y*i))));
}

console.log(flatten(vertices));

//
//  Configure WebGL
//
gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
gl.clearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );

//  Load shaders and initialize attribute buffers

var program = initShaders( gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader" );
gl.useProgram( program );

// Load the data into the GPU

var colorBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(vertexColors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);    

var vColor = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vColor");
gl.vertexAttribPointer( vColor, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 ); //error produced here
gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vColor );

var buffer2 = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer2 );
gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW );

var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );

// Associate out shader variables with our data buffer

render();
};

function render() {
    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
    gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);//draw the field - field coordinates start at 0-4
    gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLE_FAN, 5, 100);//draw the circle - circle    coordinates start at 5-100
}
```

Comment: There are only 7 colors but your draw call tries to access 100.

Comment: @tkausl, thank you. That got rid of the error, I used `drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 7)`however, my `drawArrays()` is now only drawing a few points. How would I draw all my points with only the 7 colours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using vertex colors as attributes to color your shapes you need one vertex color PER vertex. In other words if you have 1000 vertices each vertex needs a position and a color.

If you're using a constant color per shape then you can do one of these.

1. Use a constant vertex attribute

   ```
   // disabling the array means this attribute uses a constant value
   gl.disableVertexAttribArray(vertexColorLocation);

   // set the constant value
   gl.vertexAttrib4f(vertexColorLocation, r, g, b, a);
   ```

   Note: using constant values on attributes is not a common usage case
2. Use a uniform instead

   change your shader to

   ```
   <script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
       attribute vec4 vPosition;

       void main() {
           gl_Position = vPosition;
       }
   </script>

   <script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
       precision mediump float;
       uniform vec4 fColor;     // <=- changed

       void main() {
           gl_FragColor = fColor;
       }
   </script>
   ```

   Now you can set the color of your shape by setting the fColor uniform

   ```
   // at init time
   var fColorLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "fColor");

   // at render time
   gl.uniform4f(fColorLocation, r, g, b, a);
   ```

Comment: Thanks, @gman. This is explain exactly what I was trying to do, and it worked.